# How do I use my points to create Nearest Neighbors Clusters Map?

Tags: qgis-plugins, visualisation, nearest-neighbor, crimestat

[image]I have points which I am trying to analyse using visualist tools in QGIS and I am an encountering a common error ( see attached image ). How best can I rectify the problem? Tried several times to correct my points to no  avail.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Unfortunately, you didn't include any information that could be used to help you, not even the error you mentioned as "attached". Like this, any answer would be just guessing in the dark. Please see the [tour] to see how this site works and than update your question, providing more details - otherwise, it risks to be closed.

Comment: Thank you,i just updated the question and added a picture.

Comment: For next questions: always include error messages as text, not as image. Describe what exatly you tried, as detailed as possible: I have a point layer, tried to run Nearest Neighours and got this errror: .... A question like yours is normally closed as lacking focused information. To avoid this unpleasant experience, try to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You must convert you point layer from multi- to single part: `Menu Vector / Geometry Tools / Multipart to singleparts`.